# Polls in Google group

Tags: google-groups

Is there any way to create a poll in a Google group?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a "[Form](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=15166)" from within [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) and publish that form to your group.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Moderator](http://www.google.com/moderator/) is a decent utility for polls. If you use Google Apps, you can have some Apps specific functionality. But to answer your question, no, there is no polling functionality in Google Groups.